# Async method body expression without await

Tags: c#, async-await

I've recently discovered this behaviour of the Method body expression below.

```
async Task Foo() { return Task.Delay(1000); } //won't compile
async Task Foo1() => Task.Delay(1000); //compiles but returns a new CompletedTask
```

The regular method definition won't compile, which is fine. The method body expression version compiles, but to code below. It is a surprise. Can anyone explain why the method body expression compiles like this?

```
async Task Foo1()
{
    Task.Delay(1000);
    return;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it compiles that way?

Comment: Running tests. `await Foo1()` returns instantly

Comment: Yes, because you're not awaiting anything. Why is it a surprise? `Task.Delay(1000)` returns a `Task` that you're ignoring.

Comment: I think that aiming for code that just compiles, you are setting the bar too low. Most programmers aim first and foremost at producing a specific behavior.

Comment: Seems like the question is referring to why there is a difference in the compilation behaviour. At a glance, `Foo` and `Foo1` seem like they should be equivalent.

Comment: `async Task F() => await Task.Delay(1000);` or `Task F() => [return] Task.Delay(1000);` otherwise you are ignoring the result of `Task.Delay`. Because `async Task` is like a `void` function, you can't explicitly specify the return value, but you can `await` the result.

Comment: The code does produce a warnings for me, "This async method lacks await operators and will run synchronously...", and one saying that the Delay isn't awaited on , so execution will continue past it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `async` modifier changes what you can return in a method. If your method is async and is declared to return `Task<int>`, you cannot *literally* return a `Task<int>`. You must return `int`s instead. It becomes as if the method actually has a return type of `int`. The compiler implicitly creates a `Task<int>` based on the `int`-returning body of the method, and rewrites your method to return that `Task<int>`.

Similarly, an `async` method that is declared to return `Task` "feels like" a `void` method. You can't explicitly `return` a `Task` in it - you can only write `return;` without any return value.

Note that an expression-bodied `void`-returning method, like:

```
void Foo() => Console.ReadLine();
```

discards the expression's value and compiles to something like:

```
void Foo() {
    Console.ReadLine();
    return; // implicit
}
```

The expression body of `async Task Foo1() => Task.Delay(1000);` acts as if it were in a `void` method, so by the same pattern, it is only natural that  it would compile to:

```
async Task Foo1() {
    Task.Delay(1000);
    return; // implicit
}
```

See also the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#15611-method-body) on method bodies.

> The effective return type of a method is void if the return type is void, or if the method is async and the return type is `«TaskType»` ([§15.15.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#15151-general)). [...]
>
> [...]
>
> When the effective return type of a method is void and the method has a block body, return statements (§13.10.5) in the block shall not specify an expression. [...]
>
> When the effective return type of a method is `void` and the method has an expression body, the expression `E` shall be a `statement_expression`, and the body is exactly equivalent to a block body of the form `{ E; }`.

If you want to return the `Task`, just don't make the method `async`.

---

Note that there has been [a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/27647) where the compiler thought expression-bodied `async` methods should still return a `Task`/`Task<T>`, but it has now been fixed.

Comment: Yeah, it all makes sense from a Task equals void perspective. On the other hand, `int Foo()=> 1` returns 1, but `async Task Foo() => Task.Delay(1)` won't return the task. It would be better if it refused to compile.

Comment: @Xiaoguo Ge, Re "*It would be better if it refused to compile.*", Ignoring the value returned by a function should not be a compile error, no. A warning, maybe. But not an error.

Comment: The intention is to return the value, not to ignore it. if `int Foo()=>1` translate to `int Foo(){return 1;}`, shouldn't `async Task Foo()=>Task.Delay(1)` translate to `async Task Foo()=>{return Task.Delay(1);}` and fail?

Comment: @XiaoguoGe If the intention is to return the `Task`, you shouldn't have made it `async` in the first place. If `async Task Foo()=>Task.Delay(1)` should fail, should things like `async Task Foo()=> await GetIntAsync()` fail too? There are many cases where you want to discard the return value and just do a side effect. Either way, the compiler can't catch *every* mistake you make. If you think this is a common enough mistake to make, open a ticket on dotnet/roslyn.